# Image issue inside PDF loop

Tags: image, dompdf

I'm using DOMPDF to generate PDF's that can contain images and I'm having a weird issue with that.

The PDF is generated inside a loop and the amount of PDF's that needs to be generated varies. When there is only 1 PDF generated everything goes well. The image (or logo in this case) is getting inserted beautifully.
But when there are 2 or more PDF's that have to be generated for some reason the image is replaced with a red cross. But: the image in the first PDF generated in that batch works perfectly. So: the image in PDF #1 loads perfectly, the image in PDF #2 and up is getting replaced with a red cross.

I'm using the latest stable release of DOMPDF (v0.5.2). I've also tested with v0.5.1 but that had the same behaviour.

The server I'm testing this on runs on Linux, with PHP 5.3.8. No errors in the error-log about this (and I do have error logging enabled).

--- edit:
The "path" to the image is an absolute URL, not an absolute or relative (PHP) path and with outputting the contents of the loop to the browser (or a normal HTML email, without the PDF attachment) it displays the image (in all mails) perfectly.

--- edit2:
Using a function to flush all buffers at the end of the loop (which, unfortunately, doesn't change anything to my issue):

```
function flush_buffers()
{ 
    ob_end_flush(); 
    ob_flush(); 
    flush(); 
    ob_start(); 
}
```

An example of the loop I'm using:

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < count($cert); ++$i )
{
    // load the email-template
    ob_start();
    include($template);
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    // require dompdf
    include_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');

    // set PDF path - inside temp dir
    $newpdf = trailingslashit(realpath(sys_get_temp_dir())).$cert[$i]['coupon'].'.pdf';

    // replace shortcodes with wanted content
    $certificate = preg_replace($shortcodes, $replacements, $certificate);
    $certificate = '<html><body>'.$certificate.'</body></html>'."\n";

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF(); 
    $dompdf->load_html($certificate); 
    $dompdf->set_paper($pageformat, $orientation);
    $dompdf->render();
    save_pdf($newpdf, $dompdf->output()); // save PDF

    @flush_buffers();
}
```

One of the shortcodes is [logo] and that's getting replaced with an img-tag. As I previously mentioned: that image works fine in the first PDF, but not in the other PDF's.

Comment: Can you try the latest beta version (0.6 beta 2) ? It has improvements with files paths, and images. The SVN trunk has also a new way to handle images files, so you could also try it.

Comment: Hi Fabien, thanks for your reply :-) I was hoping to avoid using the beta, since it's a beta (and what I'm making should be used in live environments). But if you insist I should try it, I will :)

Comment: In numerous ways, the 0.6 branch is better than the 0.5 branch, and globally more stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to dompdf 0.6beta2 fixed this issue. Thanks Fabien!